# sql query failing on insert

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I have this simple, standard and easy sql query, which I cannot figure out the issue with. It seems okay on looking at it, but cannot figure out the issue... It gives me an error (which you can find below), but first, here's the insert query.

```
//DB2 CONNECTION FOR ADDING PRODUCTS
var addProducts =
  "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, DIVISION, XS, S, M, L, XL, INTER, EACH_CASE ) VALUES ('" +
  req.body.item +
  "', '" +
  req.body.description +
  "', '" +
  req.body.price +
  "', '" +
  allSizes +
  "', '" +
  req.body.category +
  "', '" +
  req.body.xs +
  "', '" +
  req.body.s +
  "', '" +
  req.body.m +
  "', '" +
  req.body.l +
  "', '" +
  req.body.xl +
  "', '" +
  inter +
  "', '" +
  each_case +
  "' )";
 
    ibmdb.open(req.session.ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
      if (err) return console.log(err + "getting error here 1");
      conn.query(addProducts, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err + "getting error here 1");
        }

        var getProductDetails = "select * from products where ITEM = '" + req.body.item + "'";
        ibmdb.open(req.session.ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
          if (err) return console.log(err + "getting error here 2");
          conn.query(getProductDetails, function (err, gianluca) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err + "getting error here 2");
            }

            var productAddedValue = ""
            console.log(gianluca)
            res.render("add-products2", {
              page_title: "add-products2",
              data: gianluca,
              userName: req.session.username,
              FN: req.session.firstname,
              LN: req.session.lastname,
              CO: req.session.company,
              productAddedValue: productAddedValue,
            });

            conn.close(function () {
              console.log("closed the function /add-products p2");
            });
          });
```

});
it gave me this error:

```
[Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0010N  The string constant beginning with "' )" does not have an ending string delimiter.  SQLSTATE=42603
] {
  error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -10,
  state: '42603'
}
```

not sure how to fix this! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can u attach the query you used to send the command to the database?

Comment: @JaisonThomas just updated the question

Comment: Use prepared statement (conn.prepare) instead of query (conn.query). Using prepared statement fixes the error due to single quote in req.body values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, was a silly error. When i was inserting the data into the db, i was adding a `'` in the description column, which was throwing the whole thing off. Thanks everyone 4 the help

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using nodejs es5 this should work, and is much much cleaner

```js
const addProducts =  `insert into PRODUCTS (ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, DIVISION, XS, S, M, L, XL, INTER, EACH_CASE) VALUES ('${req.body.item}', '${req.body.description}', '${req.body.price}', '${allSizes}', '${req.body.category}', '${req.body.xs}', '${req.body.s}', '${req.body.m}', '${req.body.l}', '${req.body.xl}', '${inter}', '${each_case}');`;
```

Comment: thanks for trying, but still gave me the same error!

Comment: does IBM have an IDE where you can test the same values in a raw string?

Comment: i updated my response by adding a `;` at the end of the SQL string

Comment: still happened. Same thing. I'm so confused on why, your answer makes so much sense to me lol. and yes they do, it seems to be working there, something with the code is off, wondering why....

Comment: maybe console log your query and see if it matches what you're expecting?